# What does this for-loop mean?

Tags: php, for-loop

I've stumbled upon a syntax in a code example I have never seen in for-loops before in PHP.

What does this do? **WHY should I use this?**

```
for(;$i<$max;){
    $i++;
    //code..
}
```

I could figure out that it **was not the same** as

```
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++) {
    //code...
}
```

I don't understand the difference between the two examples above.

If for being more specific about my thoughts.
If we have this code (taken from a solution from adventofcode):https://www.reddit.com/r/adventofcode/comments/kdf85p/2020_day_15_solutions/

```
<?php
$cap = 2020;
$bits = [5,1,9,18,13,8,0];
$i=0;
$time = [];
foreach($bits as $bit) {
    $i++;
    $time[$bit] = $i;
    $say = 0;
}

for(;$i<$cap-1;){
    $i++;
    if(isset($time[$say])) {
        $last = $time[$say];
    }
    else {
        $last = $i;
    }
    $time[$say] = $i;
    $say = $i - $last;
}
echo $say;
?>
```

**and compare that to:**

```
<?php
$cap = 2020;
$bits = [5,1,9,18,13,8,0];
$i=0;
$time = [];
foreach($bits as $bit) {
    $i++;
    $time[$bit] = $i;
    $say = 0;
}

for($i=0;$i<$cap-1;$i++){
    if(isset($time[$say])) {
        $last = $time[$say];
    }
    else {
        $last = $i;
    }
    $time[$say] = $i;
    $say = $i - $last;
}
echo $say;
?>
```

I get different results in $say.(`376 in first example and 38 in last example`).
**Why do I get different values?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between the two blocks (assuming `$i` is initialised to 0 before the `for(;$i<$max;){` loop) is that the first loop increments `$i` *before* running the loop code, where the second loop increments `$i` *after* running the loop code. As a trivial example:

```php
function code($i) {
    echo "$i\n";
}

$max = 3;
$i = 0;
for(;$i<$max;){
    $i++;
    code($i);
}

for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++) {
    code($i);
}
```

The output of the first loop is:

```
1
2
3
```

while the output of the second loop is:

```
0
1
2
```

Note (as pointed out by @IMSoP), the condition clause is executed at the beginning of the loop, and can have side-effects, so you could also emulate the first loop with this code:

```
for($i=0;$i++<$max;) {
    code($i);
}
```

Comment: Aha thanks a lot! You could basically (from my example) type for($i=7;$i<$cap-1;) instead and it will give the expected result (because $i is 7 when starting the loop). There are no way of making $i processed having the arguments within the for-clause e.g. for(;$i<cap-1;<$process i$ first> ? (I'm just curious)

Comment: No; the increment clause in a standard `for` loop is always executed after all the code in the loop. However you could increment `$i` before the loop and change the end condition to `$i < $cap` to have the same effect

Comment: @Nick The "increment clause" (third expression) is always evaluated at the end of each iteration, but the "condition clause" (second expression) is evaluated at the beginning of each iteration, can have side-effects, and can be a list of expressions. So if you want the increment at the beginning of each iteration, you can just throw it in there.

Comment: @IMSoP you are of course correct, I've added a note to the answer showing another way of implementing the loop using a side effect.

Answer (score 2):

Well based on the PHP docs:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

> for loops are the most complex loops in PHP. They behave like their C
> counterparts. The syntax of a for loop is:
>
> for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
> statement

While:

> Each of the expressions can be empty or contain multiple expressions
> separated by commas.

So it's just a way to "save code" when your first expression of the for-loop is "obvious", So instead of mentioning the default obvious expression - you just "skip" it.

**According to your example:**

```
for(;$i<$cap-1;)
```

we skipped the first expression (expr1) as $i has been already defined as 0 (`$i = 0;`) earlier in the code block so it's "skippable". Doesn't affect the code.

But, The third expression:

> At the end of each iteration, expr3 is evaluated (executed).

Since we don't mention it in the loop, we are responsible to handle the "increasement" (in this case) of $i in the loop itself.

However - the main difference in the code is that if you mention the third expression - it's evaluated **at the end of each iteration** but in the code block (your example) - we increase the $i variable at the beginning of the code.

Comment: I've updated my code and hope it got clearer now what I meant :-)

Comment: Aha thanks a lot! You could basically (from my example) type for($i=7;$i<$cap-1;) instead and it will give the expected result. the main reason for doing this in this case is simply that $i should be processed in the beginning of the loop?

Comment: $i = 7 because it is seven when starting the for-loop.

Comment: Rather than "a way to save code", I would say this is a mistake by someone who didn't realise they could just use `while($i<$max)` instead. Given that PHP loops don't have their own scope, a `for` loop with no expression in the third position is pretty pointless.

Answer (score 1):

C-style `for` loops are a rather peculiar piece of syntax. They actually consist of three expressions, any of which can do anything you like, or even be empty:

- An expression to execute for its side effects once before the loop begins
- An expression to evaluate at the beginning of each iteration, to see if the loop should terminate
- An expression to execute for its side effects at the end of each iteration

The most common way to *use* them is:

- Initialise a counter of some sort
- Check if the counter has reached some value
- Increment or decrement the counter

But those aren't built into the language at all, and leaving one of the expressions out doesn't apply any default behaviour, it just does nothing - except that leaving the second expression empty always evaluates to `true`.

So, for instance:

- `for(;true;)` is an infinite loop: it does nothing, checks `true`, and does nothing again
- `for(;;)` is the same infinite loop, because the empty expression in the middle is considered `true`
- `for($i=0;;)` is just the same infinite loop, but with `$i` initialised to `0` before running it
- `for(;true;foo())` is the same loop, but with the function `foo()` run at the end of every iteration

In your case, the loop is `for(;$i<$max;)` which breaks down to:

- Before starting the loop, do nothing
- At the beginning of each iteration, terminate if the expression `$i<$max` happens to be false
- At the end of each iteration, do nothing

It doesn't do anything to control what values `$i` and `$max` have before or during the loop.

In fact, it's just the same as `while($i<$max)` and would probably be much clearer if written that way.

The example shown seems to have ended up that way because the author wanted to move the `$i++` to the beginning of each iteration, rather than the end (although why they also left out the `$i=0` I'm not sure). But the `for` syntax supports that too! You can actually include *multiple* expressions with a comma between in any of the three positions; if they're in the second position, the last one is what determines if the loop exits.

So you can do this:

```
for($i=0; $i++,$i<=$max; )
```

Now, `$i` will be incremented at the *beginning* of the loop; since it will be incremented before the test, you have to also adjust the condition from `<` to `<=` to make sure it runs for one more iteration.

For that particular case, there's another way as well: incrementing a variable returns a value. If you write `++$i` it returns the value *after* incrementing, and if you write `$i++` it returns the value *before* incrementing. So both of these would also work:

```
for($i=0; ++$i <= 10; ) echo $i, PHP_EOL;
for($i=0; $i++ < 10; ) echo $i, PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: ah. thanks a lot! yes a while-loop seems more "natural" to use for me anyway :-) Just out of curioisty... There are no way of processing the $i++ in the for-clause (e.g. for ($i=0;$i<$max;$process in beginning of loop) ?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Actually, yes, see the extra examples I've edited in.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, $i is registered somewhere before. so $i can be 0 or other zero, because if you use code like

```
for(;$i<$max;){
    $i++;
    //code..
}
```

you got error Undefined variable $i in and later $i is registered.

```
/* example 1 */

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}

/* example 2 */

for ($i = 1; ; $i++) {
    if ($i > 10) {
        break;
    }
    echo $i;
}

/* example 3 */

$i = 1;
for (; ; ) {
    if ($i > 10) {
        break;
    }
    echo $i;
    $i++;
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

what is your point?